# Is there a dedicated milli-sec precision timestamp data structure in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For instance, in q, there is a dedicated time struct, such as 11:59:59.999, which I can use in a table as a column. Is there anything like this in pandas?

I read the doc and there seems to be quite comprehensive examples for timestamp on a daily resolution, which is good for fund managers, I guess. Is there a milli-second resolution time struct?

Comment: Pandas supports numpy datetime64 which uses 64 bits to store time, more specifically it supports millisecond representation with an absolute resolution of 2.9e6 BC to 2.9e6 AD I think that should cover your requirements, is there anything specifically you want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes there is!

### It's called `Timestamp`!

`pandas` has support for up to **nanosecond** resolution using its own `Timestamp` class which is a subclass of `datetime.datetime`:

```
In [6]: pd.Timestamp('now') + np.timedelta64(100, 'ns')
Out[6]: Timestamp('2013-10-06 21:09:19.000000100', tz=None)

In [7]: isinstance(_6, datetime.datetime)
Out[7]: True
```

Note that all date-like `Series` objects are represented as `datetime64[ns]`:

```
In [8]: Series(date_range('now', periods=5))
Out[8]:
0   2013-10-06 21:11:37
1   2013-10-07 21:11:37
2   2013-10-08 21:11:37
3   2013-10-09 21:11:37
4   2013-10-10 21:11:37
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This is true even if I only specify `'D'` (day) frequency on construction:

```
In [11]: Series(date_range('1/1/2001', periods=5, freq='D'))
Out[11]:
0   2001-01-01 00:00:00
1   2001-01-02 00:00:00
2   2001-01-03 00:00:00
3   2001-01-04 00:00:00
4   2001-01-05 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The `values` attribute of `Series` yields a `numpy.ndarray` of `datetime64[ns]` dtype:

```
In [12]: s = Series(date_range('1/1/2001', periods=5, freq='D'))

In [13]: s.values
Out[13]:
array(['2000-12-31T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
       '2001-01-01T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
       '2001-01-02T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
       '2001-01-03T19:00:00.000000000-0500',
       '2001-01-04T19:00:00.000000000-0500'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

You can also create date ranges with millisecond frequency (note the `'L'` here; that's just the name we give to milliseconds since `'MS'` is used for the `MonthBegin` offset):

```
In [18]: date_range('2013/11/1', freq='ms', periods=10)
Out[18]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-11-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-11-01 00:00:00.009000]
Length: 10, Freq: L, Timezone: None
```

In `pandas` 0.13.0, you'll be able to create nanosecond ranges with `date_range`, this turns out to be useful for data sets with sizable sampling rates, e.g., extracellular recordings in neurophysiology:

```
In [15]: date_range('2013/11/1', freq='N', periods=10)
Out[15]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-11-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-11-01 00:00:00.000000009]
Length: 10, Freq: N, Timezone: None
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas supports using numpy datetime 64 objects which use 64-bits to store time. This has enough absolute resolution for milliseconds from  2.9e6 BC to 2.9e6 AD, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html) for further information. You can convert dates or datestrings to datetimes easily in pandas, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html) and a useful [IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/changhiskhan/talks/master/pydata2012/pandas_timeseries.ipynb).

As @PhillipCloud has commented and clarified in his answer this is represented as datetime64[ns] so it is nanoseconds which should be fine enough resolution for what you need.

Comment: Everyone's always hatin' on the [Hadean eon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadean) ;) (+1)

Comment: @EdChum Minor point: `pandas` *does* support `datetime64` objects, but that's not how they are represented. We have had quite a time making a compatibility layer between numpy 1.6's and numpy 1.7's drastically different behavior w.r.t dates/times/timedeltas, so IMHO they should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @PhillipCloud Yes, I should have made this clearer in my answer, I have been caught out by the code changes between numpy 1.6 and 1.7 causing datetime functions to no longer work in my python code.

Comment: @EdChum Yep, we try *extremely* hard to get around that with `pandas`. Representing everything with nanoseconds makes the implementation a bit easier, but by no means is it pretty :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud Well I'd like to take this opportunity to thank you guys for a sterling job, one of the best python libraries I have used and a pleasure (usually ;), barring my lack of knowledge) each and every time I have to analyse data.

Comment: Glad to hear it, I feel the same way! I've only been hacking on pandas for a few months, so I can only take a very small amount of credit :)